# Python 2.7 requests.get when used with HTTPDigestAuth drops query string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi?query=limits", auth=HTTPDigestAuth(self.username, self.password))
print(r.url)
>>http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi
```

The printed url has lost the query string. If I remove the auth parameter, the url retains the query string at the end of the url correctly.

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi?query=limits")
print(r.url)
>>http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi?query=limits
```

I've tried passing the query using the 'params' keyword and the same problem occurs.

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.25.243:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi", params={'query': 'limits'}, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(self.username, self.password))
print(r.url)
>>http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi
```

Using basic auth generates the correct url.

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi?query=limits", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.password))
print(r.url)
>>http://192.168.28.111:80/is-cgi/com/ctw.cgi?query=limits
```

Anyone know what might be going on? It seems like there should be a simple solution, but this is behaving very strangely.

Comment: Try setting `allow_redirects = False`. My guess is that in the example with the auth, the webserver is returning a 3XX redirect, but probably returning a 4XX when you are not passing the credentials.

Comment: @jordanm this looks like the case! When I set allow_redirects = False I get an HTTP code 302 and the url looks correct. However, I still don't get the data I need from the endpoint. I can get it using the browser or Postman, so I'm wondering how python is handling that differently. Thanks for the help, I'm getting closer now :)